# How to silence long long integer constant warning from GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gcc-warning, long-long

I have some code using large integer literals as follows:

```
if(nanoseconds < 1'000'000'000'000)
```

This gives the compiler warning `integer constant is too large for 'long' type [-Wlong-long]`.  However, if I change it to:

```
if(nanoseconds < 1'000'000'000'000ll)
```

...I instead get the warning `use of C++11 long long integer constant [-Wlong-long]`.

I would like to disable this warning just for this line, but without disabling -Wlong-long or using -Wno-long-long for the entire project.  I have tried surrounding it with:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wlong-long"
...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

but that does not seem to work here with this warning.  Is there something else I can try?

I am building with `-std=gnu++1z`.

Edit: minimal example for the comments:

```
#include <iostream>
auto main()->int {
  double nanoseconds = 10.0;
  if(nanoseconds < 1'000'000'000'000ll) {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Building with `g++ -std=gnu++1z -Wlong-long test.cpp` gives `test.cpp:6:20: warning: use of C++11 long long integer constant [-Wlong-long]`

I should mention this is on a 32bit platform, Windows with MinGW-w64 (gcc 5.1.0) - the first warning does not seem to appear on my 64bit Linux systems, but the second (with the `ll` suffix) appears on both.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this warning and it also makes no sense because why shouldn't C++11 features be available with `-std=gnu++1z`? Can you show a minimal working example and give your exact compiler version and flags you use?

Comment: `long long  nanoseconds = 10;  if(nanoseconds < 1000000000000ll )     std::cout<<1000000000000ll;` works for me in `gcc5.2` with option `-std=gnu++1z`

Comment: I have updated the question with a minimal example and a commandline to reproduce.  I agree it makes no sense to be warning about using C++11 features in this situation.

Comment: What about a crude workaround like `((long long)1000000) * 1000000`?

Comment: This is a gcc bug, here's [another example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d9ffed39a10416e) with a similar warning. It looks like adding `-Wlong-long` explicitly causes the language dialect to be ignored.

Comment: @Praetorian that's interesting - has the bug been reported?  I can't find any mention of it.

Comment: I couldn't either, you should file one and link to it in an answer.

Comment: @Praetorian It's not a bug to get the warning you explicitly request.

Comment: @hvd Re-reading the documentation, I agree with you. When I read it last night, somehow I took it to mean `-pedantic` always enables `-Wlong-long` and that the warning is supposed to be emitted when you have < C++11 enabled. Riot, sorry for the suggestion to file a bogus bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the C++11 warning when using the `ll` suffix may be [a gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68284). (Thanks @praetorian)

A workaround (inspired by @nate-eldredge's comment) is to avoid using the literal and have it produced at compile time with constexpr:

```
int64_t constexpr const trillion = int64_t(1'000'000) * int64_t(1'000'000);
if(nanoseconds < trillion) ...
```